# Integration Using Trigonometric Substitutions with $x^2$ and $\sqrt x$ in denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I integrate a function in this form:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{a+x^2}}dx$$

I know I need to use trigonometric substitution but don't see how to apply it for this form of function. What should I look for when integrating these types of functions?

Comment: set $x=\sqrt{a}\tan(t)$

Comment: Alternately, let $x=\sqrt a~\sinh t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$x = \sqrt a\tan\theta \implies dx = \sqrt a\sec^2 \theta$$ and $x^2 = a \tan^2\theta$

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{a+x^2}}\,dx = \int \frac {\sqrt a \sec^2 \theta}{a\tan^2\theta\sqrt{a + a \tan^2 \theta}}\,d\theta$$

$$ = \int \dfrac{\sec^2\theta}{a \tan^2\theta \sqrt{\underbrace{1+ \tan^2}_{\sec^2 \theta}\theta}}\,d\theta$$

$$ = \frac 1a\int \dfrac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta\sec\theta}\,d\theta$$

$$=\frac 1a \int \dfrac{\cos \theta\,d\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = \frac{-1}{a\sin\theta} + C $$  Now, since $$x = \sqrt a \tan\theta, \tan\theta = \frac x{\sqrt a}\implies \sin\theta = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{a+x^2}}$$
So $$\frac{-1}{a\sin\theta} + C = -\dfrac{\sqrt{a+x^2}}{ax} + C$$

Comment: I've tried this but get stuck at: $$\int\frac{sec\theta}{atan^2\theta}d\theta$$

Also how do you know to use this substitution?

Comment: That's correct simplification, but now you can simply multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 \theta$ to get a nice simplification. See my post.

Comment: Okay, so then I let $u=sin\theta$ and after integrating ended up with $$\frac{-1}{asin\theta}+c$$

Is this correct, and if so how can I get it back in terms of $x$?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this - where does the 3 in the denominator come from?

Comment: I hope my last edit helps...not sure how I let that slip in...typo, I suspect. In my comment, $3$ should be replaced by $a$!

Comment: Okay, thanks. And last thing, because: $$tan\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a}}$$ using $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, you'd get: $$c^2=(\sqrt{a})^2+(x)^2=a+x^2$$ so $$c = \sqrt{a+x^2}$$and therefore $$sin\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{a+x^2}}$$So the final answer would be $\frac{-\sqrt{a+x^2}}{ax}+C$ right?

Comment: Yes, of course. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

For this one use $$x=\sqrt{a}\tan u$$

In general;

> $$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}:\text{ sub } x=a\sin u$$
>
> $$\sqrt{a^2+x^2}:\text{ sub } x=a\tan u$$
>
> $$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}: \text{ sub } x=a \sec u$$

Comment: I've tried this but get stuck at: $$\int\frac{sec\theta}{atan^2\theta}d\theta$$

Comment: @Daniel You should have gotten $$\sqrt a\int \frac{\cot u\csc u}{a^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}u =\frac1a \int \frac{\cos u}{\sin^2 u} \mathrm{d}u$$ EDIT; nevermind, I misunderstood what you meant by $atan^2\theta$